# Image merging in plotly with transparency

Tags: plotly-dash, transparency

I'm struggling to come up with a solution using Plotly to reproduce the following code which uses matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=100)
image = np.random.random([300, 5000])
image2 = np.ones([300, 5000])
plt.imshow(image, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="gray_r", aspect="auto", alpha=0.5)
plt.imshow(image2, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="seismic", aspect="auto", alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

My goal is to merge two arrays together using transparency parameters for each array. One array is displayed in grey color, another in red color (or seismic). Plotly imshow does not have alpha parameter, so I'm a bit confused about how to implement this simple code using plotly. I need this for my dash plotly app.